Blue colour while hexacyanoferrate(II) reacts with Hg2+
From this article, the author noticed that when [Fe(CN)6]4- reacts with Hg2+ in a 1:2 molar ratio, a white precipitate formed, then turn blue color. What is the chemical that is responsible for this blue color?

It has been observed through an independent experiment conducted at low [Fe(CN)6]4- that mixing of [Fe(CN)6]4- and HgCl2 in a 1:2 molar ratio leads to the formation of white precipitate, which quickly turned into blue color. This observation further strengthens the idea of adduct/binuclear complex formations between K4[Fe(CN)6] and HgCl2 in 1:1 stoichiometric amount in solution. The existence of a similar complex formation between [Fe(CN)6]4- and Hg(CN)2 has been postulated by Beck [36].


I would consider possibility of formation of Berlin blue.

You mean there is a formation of Fe2+, isn't it?

I agree with Poutnik's comment that we may have formed Berlin blue (also "Prussian blue"), which is a combined Fe(II)-Fe(III) cyanide complex. The standard reduction potential of the ferricyanide complex ion is about 370 mV[1], several hundred mV below that of water-complexed iron(III) or cations of the noble metal mercury listed in common standard potential tables. So we can expect the mercury ions to oxidize the iron(II) to iron(III) in the cyanide compound forming said Berlin blue.
Reference

Peter A. Rock. "The Standard Oxidation Potential of the Ferrocyanide-Ferricyanide Electrode at 25° and the Entropy of Ferrocyanide Ion". J. Phys. Chem. 1966, 70, 2, 576–580. https://doi.org/10.1021/j100874a042

